# Regex for 5 digit number with optional characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex to validate a field where the user can enter a 5 digit number with the option of adding a `/` followed by 3 letters. I have tried quite a few variations of the following code:

```
^(\d{5})+?([/]+[A-Z]{1,3})?
```

But I just can't seem to get what I want.

For instance l would like the user to either enter a 5 digit number such as `12345` with the option of adding a forward slash followed by any 3 letters such as `12345/WFE`.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't seem to get what l want"?

Comment: I meant that l couldn't get the regex code in my question to validate how l wanted it to.

Comment: That... still doesn't make it clearer, I'm afraid. You should put samples of strings you want to match and others which are matching which shouldn't match, or vice versa next time you have a question. You regex will work for valid codes, but will also accept some invalid ones. Depending on what you're trying to do and the context, your current regex can and will work, but it won't in other context. One last thing, you should mention the language you're using the regex in. It varies on different platforms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want:

```
^\d{5}(?:/[A-Z]{3})?$
```

You might have to escape that forward slash depending on your regex flavor.

Explanation:

- [`^`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) - start of string anchor
- [`\d{5}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) - 5 digits
- `(?:/[A-Z]{3})` - non-capturing group consisting of a literal `/` followed by 3 uppercase letters (depending on your needs you could consider making this a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) by removing the `?:`).
- [`?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) - 0 or 1 of what precedes (in this case that's the non-capturing group directly above).
- [`$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) - end of string anchor

All in all, the regex looks like this:

[image]

Comment: There is a tool for generating such a nice graphs or you do it for your own?

Comment: This one worked! Thanks. Having joined the site today l was very surprised at how quick everyone answered. Thanks to everyone who provided and answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex

```
/^\d{5}(?:\/[a-zA-Z]{3})?$/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d{5}(?:/[A-Z]{3})?$
```

Here it is in practice (this is a great site to test your regexes):
http://regexr.com?36h9m

Answer (score 2):

```
^(\d{5})(\/[A-Z]{3})?
```

Tested in [rubular](http://rubular.com/)